# Why Rails 5.0 on Windows 7 with RailsInstaller is rendering index.html.erb view from the gems directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, erb

I'm using Rails 5 on Windows 7 by RailsInstaller. I'm following RailsGuides to build the blog.

When I do change the `index.html.erb` file to display `<h1>Hello Rails</h1>`, I get the same (default, vendor provided) view result.

Puma server gives me this log line:

```
 Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
```

Any help for what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serve `.erb` files out of `public`. The `public` directory is for static files.

If you want a request for `index.html` to be served out of `public`, your file must be called `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/routes.rb` you need to create the default `root`. For example:

```
root to: "welcome#index"
```

Where: `welcome` is the name of the controller and `index` is the name of the view.

Regards